# Pandas: copying values from column.UID to to either column8 or column9, depending on the length of the value

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a data frame with one of the columns (UID) having 7 numbers or 10 numbers.

I have written a regex to identify 7 or 10 numbers (thanks to a very similar question in stackoverflow). These seem to work well on a text file.

```
no_7 = re.compile('(?<![0-9])[0-9]{7}(?![0-9])')

no_9 = re.compile('(?<![0-9])[0-9]{9}(?![0-9])')
```

Again, thanks to stackoverflow, I have written the following.

If the column is of 7 numbers, the values are copied to the second to last column.

```
df['column8']=df['UID'].apply(lambda x: x if(x == re.findall(no_7, x)) else 'NaN')
```

If the column is of 10 numbers, the column are copied to the last column

```
df['column9']=df['UID'].apply(lambda x: X if(x == re.findall(no_9, x)) else 'NaN')
```

While debugging the problem I was able to find out that the regex is never able to read the column with numbers as a number.

Regex complains:

> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

I have tried setting column "UID" pd.to_numeric

I have tried setting column "UID" df["UID"].astype(int)

I have tried setting column "UID" df["UID"].apply(np.int64)

All assuming that the problem is that the column is incorrectly formatted, which I think it not, any longer.

Comment: Can you edit your question to make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Please provide input dataframe and expected output as text.

Comment: Also, why don't you just use the length of the string to determine the "length" of the number `df['UID'].astype(str).apply(len)`

Answer (score 0):

You are obviously using the `int` type in your column and need `str` to apply string operations. You can convert using:

```
df['UID'].astype(str)
```

However, there are probably much better ways to do what you want, please improve your question as requested for a better response.